# Memory warning in Xamarin iOS while loading multiple images in UIView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, out-of-memory

I'm working on Xamarin iOS project. I have to load the images depends on help menu choice. I have a view controller with UIImageView and every time I'm adding the list of images I have to show a list and showing the Images. It works fine for two or three menu options (times). After few clicks app is crashing due to memory.  I tried to clear the List on Close button click even though it is crashing. Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the relevant code and screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful with adding "heavy" resources like images. Rule of thumb:

1. Keep only in memory what you really need, means: clean up everything that's not in the view port. Use `UICollectionView`or `UITableView`, they support dequeueuing reusable cells (see Xamarin docs for more information).

   2. Clean up **everything** you don't need anymore. Make sure it's cleaned up for sure.

For some more information, see here: https://thomasbandt.com/xamarinios-memory-pitfalls